# how to obtain coefficients for rolling linear and non linear regression in r

Tags: r

i am performing rolling regression using roll_regress, the code is

```
model1 <- roll_regres(Y ~ x1 + x2, z, width = 12L, do_downdates = FALSE, do_compute = c("sigmas", "r.squareds"))
poscoef <- model1$coefs
```

while this works. In essence as of my data x2 is negatively correlated with Y, so change the sign as shown in below code. but the now the problem is the coefficients of x2 were noteven generating.

```
model1 <- roll_regres(Y ~ x1 - x2, z, width = 12L, do_downdates = FALSE, do_compute = c("sigmas", "r.squareds"))
poscoef <- model1$coefs
```

So, what should I do to obtain the coefficients of X2 with being x2 negatively relating to Y. if possible please specify code.

Actually, I would like to try it in a nonlinear framework too. but  I am not able to find rolling function of non-linear methods in R

Comment: The negative correlation shouldn't matter - you still use a +. Alternatively, try `Y ~ x1 + I(-x2)` in the formula

Comment: @AllanCameron  thanks for the suggestion. by running the way you mentioned, I got the same values as y ~ x1 + X2 with a negative sign before the coefficients. is it a problem or can I go ahead with these results? and is there any package or code that can help me to run the same in nonlinear regression?

Comment: The negative in front of the coefficients dictate that X2 is negatively correlated to Y. You should not use `-X2` since that is simply `(-1)X2` and the `-1` will be absorbed into the coefficient to obtain `-b`.

Comment: The minus sign means something different than an arithmetic operation in the context of R formula. In an R formula `-X2` is not the same as `(-1)X2`, just as X2^2 is not X2 squared.

Comment: Greetings! Next time it would be great if you could provide some reproducible data that others can go over with you. Simply use the `dput` command on your dataset and paste it into your question so people can show you where you are going right or wrong.